# Enable WindowsForms button property wont work

Tags: c#

i have a windows forms app which i want  a certain button to change to enable if the textbox is not empty  i tried to compare it to string.Empty but it wont work so i decided to compare to TextLength wont work either ..
Code down below:

```
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (firstDisplayTxtBox.TextLength > 0)
        {

            plusButton.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
```

mayble i place the if statement in the wrong method Let me know where i am wrong Big Thanks for helpers

Comment: is the textbox value is set at the time of  `Form1_Activated` event fired?

Comment: If the `plusButton` is already `enabled` when the event fires… then it will remain `enabled` even if `firstDisplayTxtBox.TextLength == 0` shouldn’t there be an `else` clause with `plusButton.Enabled = false;` ?

Comment: I sometimes use `plusButton.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstDisplayTxtBox.Text);` which will disable `plusButton` if `firstDisplayTxtBox.Text` is `null` or `string.empty`, or if it consists of exclusively white-space characters. Otherwise, `plusButton` will be enabled. Also, I would put that in the `TextChanged` event like @Auditive recommended in his answer.

Comment: Thank everyone  i will do as you said and see if there is any problem

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you want to use `TextChanged` event, which fires every time when text in your `firstDisplayTxtBox` is changed.

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   firstDisplayTxtBox.TextChanged += OnTextChange;
}

private void OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    plusButton.Enabled = firstDisplayTxtBox.Text.Length > 0
}
```

or

[image]